# Proper way of separating a sentence in semantic HTML5

Tags: css, html

As a noob developer I'm trying to learn html5 and css from scratch with a proper and neat way. So, I'll try my luck with semantics, semantic elements, document outline etc.

In a section let's say we have some paragraphs. It is ok for me using `<p>`s when they are necessary. But I want to separate just **one sentence** from previous and next paragraph. That sentence is telling an other story, fact, information etc. This is why I want to separate it.

Here is an example. This is my section about coffee grinding (just an example):

> Grinding
>
> The whole coffee beans are ground, also known as milling, to
>   facilitate the brewing process. The fineness of the grind strongly
>   affects brewing. Brewing methods that expose coffee grounds to heated
>   water for longer require a coarser grind than faster brewing methods.
>   Beans that are too finely ground for the brewing method in which they
>   are used will expose too much surface area to the heated water and
>   produce a bitter, harsh, "over-extracted" taste. At the other extreme,
>   an overly coarse grind will produce weak coffee unless more is used.
>   Due to the importance of a grind's fineness, a uniform grind is highly
>   desirable.
>
> If a brewing method is used in which the time of exposure of the
>   ground coffee to the heated water is adjustable, then a short brewing
>   time can be used for finely ground coffee. This produces coffee of
>   equal flavor yet uses less ground coffee. A blade grinder does not
>   cause frictional heat buildup in the ground coffee unless used to
>   grind very large amounts as in a commercial operation. A fine grind
>   allows the most efficient extraction but coffee ground too finely will
>   slow down filtration or screening.
>
> (hr here)
>
> Ground coffee deteriorates faster than roasted beans because of the 
>   greater surface area exposed to oxygen. Many coffee drinkers grind the 
>   beans themselves immediately before brewing.
>
> (hr here)
>
> Spent coffee grinds can be reused for hair care or
>   skin care as well as in the garden. These can also be used as
>   biodiesel fuel.[1]
>
> (hr here)
>
> There are four methods of grinding coffee for
>   brewing: burr-grinding, chopping, pounding, and roller grinding.

Those tiny sentences give different information from the other paragraphs. 
Maybe, this question is about English language, maybe I'm not quite right about separating those since I'm not a native speaker of English. But, I decided to separate them, and here I'm.

So, instead of using `<p>` I thought about using `<hr` with a 0 opacity. After that, I thought I can use this for other `<p>`s. So, lots of `<hr>`s in a section! Now:

1. Is it OK using an `<hr>` like this (0 opacity)?
2. How do you handle similar issues?

Comment: What about using a span to wrap the special sentence, with an appropriate class? Can you give some example HTML to give us a better idea of what you're looking for?

Comment: It depends on the sentence, but it sounds like you can use an <aside> element for this.

Comment: I added a simple sample.

Comment: @BoltClock, thank you for bringing up `<aside>`.

Answer (score 0):

No, using a `<hr>` tag inside a `<p>` tag would not be considered semantic HTML. There are two reasons for this:

1. `<hr>` is not allowed inside `<p>` by spec (see [phrasing content](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#kinds-of-content-phrasing-content) to learn more).
2. According to the `<hr>` tag definition, it's used for "...thematic break, e.g., a scene change in a story, or a transition to another topic within a section of a reference book".

What you're describing in general would constitute under [footnotes](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#footnotes) according to the HTML spec, so I highly recommend reading it in detail to get a better idea on all the possibilities of covering it.

That said, as already mentioned in the comments, an `<aside>` tags seems most fit for the kind of content in your example. From the spec:

> The `aside` element represents a section of a page that consists of
>   content that is tangentially related to the content of the parenting
>   sectioning content, and which could be considered separate from that
>   content. Such sections are often represented as sidebars in printed
>   typography.

Comment: Thank you for the footnotes link and for the answer. `<aside>` is doing what I want actually. But, the thing is here those sentences are like the other ones (big paragraph), just a different info. So, if I can make them `<aside>`, that means I can make the big ones too. Then, instead of using `<p>`s, I will use `<aside>`s. Now, is it better using just `<p>`s here? Or making the whole section a list maybe? And if we don't want to use a list, what would be your approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `<cite>` for citation, or `<kbd>` for Keyboard text